# Windows network performance drops when inside the AWS VPC but not from outside VPC

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services

The application comprises of two Windows IIS webservers. These web servers are used to upload image files.

The webservers were initially hosted inside an Amazon VPC. VPC is connected to corporate network through Direct Connect. The internet users come through an internet facing load balancer hosted in corporate network and the load balancer forwards the traffic to the two servers in Amazon VPC (i.e., there is no internet gateway in the VPC - all traffic is routed through load balancer in the corporate network, goes through the Direct Connect and reaches the server). When the number of users is high, we see that the network rate drops - it was verified that the Direct Connect was still not fully used (it had only utilized 30-40% of capacity). The server had low CPU utilization at the time, but the number of bytes coming in had dropped to very low levels.

However when the server was moved outside the VPC, in to corporate network, the servers work without any network drop.

Any suggestions on how to go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Is this many small requests (eg web serving) or large requests like file downloads? Did you check CPU utilization of your on-premise routers? I wonder if there's some kind of I/O limitation on the EC2 instances, T instances ran out of CPU credits, or perhaps your EBS volumes ran out of IO credits? The connection to your on-premise servers is lower latency and probably has more CPU available, maybe that's why they work better.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It is many small requests - we also saw this same behavior with larger payloads. The utilization is low on the CPU and so is the network bandwidth utilization. The server was also upgraded - using m4 series (going up from large to 2xlarge). Initially there will be drop in the throughput and after a while, the server starts processing the connections again.. It is strange.

Comment: To be that suggest I/O or that a cache needs to be populated. Can you please have a think about that, then edit your question to be as complete as you can, expanding on the comment you made above.